# ui-router access parameter in templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there any way to access the parameter passed from the Url so I can tell the templateUrl which template to use?

```
stateProvider
  .state('management', {
    url: '/management/{viewName}',
    templateUrl: '/templates/{viewName}',//something like this
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular-UI-Router - getting content of dynamic template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386651/angular-ui-router-getting-content-of-dynamic-template). Specifically note the top comment on the accepted answer

Comment: thank you...you may close this now